# dlrs_CommSubscriptionConsentTrigger: execution of AfterInsert

Tags: trigger

I got this error after installing the DLRS open source app to make a roll up summary from a lookup relationship... I'm trying to create a consentement for a specific contact and when saving, I got this.
Here is the entire error:

> dlrs_CommSubscriptionConsentTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid id: Tue Jun 28 00:00:00 GMT 2022 (dlrs) Trigger.dlrs_CommSubscriptionConsentTrigger: line 7, column 1

here is the child trigger:

```java
/**
 * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs)
 **/
trigger dlrs_ContactTrigger on Contact
    (before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update)
{
    dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler();
}
```

```java
/**
 * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs)
 **/
@IsTest
private class dlrs_ContactTest
{
    @IsTest
    private static void testTrigger()
    {
        // Force the dlrs_CommSubscriptionConsentTrigger to be invoked, fails the test if org config or other Apex code prevents this.
        dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new Contact());
    }
}
```

```java
/**
 * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs)
 **/
trigger dlrs_CommSubscriptionConsentTrigger on CommSubscriptionConsent
    (before delete, before insert, before update, after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update)
{
    dlrs.RollupService.triggerHandler(CommSubscriptionConsent.SObjectType);
}
```

```java
/**
 * Auto Generated and Deployed by the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries Tool package (dlrs)
 **/
@IsTest
private class dlrs_CommSubscriptionConsentTest
{
    @IsTest
    private static void testTrigger()
    {
        // Force the dlrs_CommSubscriptionConsentTrigger to be invoked, fails the test if org config or other Apex code prevents this.
        dlrs.RollupService.testHandler(new CommSubscriptionConsent());
    }
}
```

Could anyone help? I don't really have coding knowledge btw

Comment: Please show the dlrs config for the rollup.  Use [edit]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  The best resource is for DLRS support is this Trailblazer group:  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000009O5pCAE?tab=discussion